# onload my website then I send a POST (with react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reload

Then I click on Create Post button  I want my website to reload.
My token is in localStorage

what should I code inside response.ok

```
 if (response.ok) {
     
      }
```

I am writing a very short version of my code here:

> 

```
const CreatePostCard = (props) => {
  const [titleInput, setTitleInput] = useState();
  const [descriptionInput, setDescriptionInput] = useState();
  const [displayCreatePost, setDisplayCreatePost] = useState(false);

  const toogleExpandCollapseForm = (e) => {
    setDisplayCreatePost((displayCreatePost) => !displayCreatePost);
    console.log("toogleDisplayCreatePost ==>", displayCreatePost);
  };
  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("onclickk activated");
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/post/";
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", titleInput);
    formData.append("description", descriptionInput);
    formData.append("image", e.target.image.files[0]);
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {

        
        if (response.ok) {
        } else {
          console.log("Failed to create post.", response);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };

return (
    <div>
         <form>
         some input ...
          <Button type="submit">Create Post</Button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
```

I use window.onload but it Didn't work it might be because it should verify my token on localStorage.
I expect to find an answer to reload the page then I click on button Create Post

Comment: You mean [location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) ?

Comment: So where is handleFormSubmit bound to the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this so when you receive `ok` response then it will `reload` your page.

```
if (response.ok) {
   window.location.reload(false);
}
```